# Help using Monotone Convergence Theorem and Extraction of Subsequences to write proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing

Q: Let $(X_n)_{n=1}^∞$  be a bounded sequence of real numbers. For all n∈ℕ, let $t_n:=\inf\{x_n: k≥n\}$. Show that $(t_n)_{n=1}^∞$ is convergent.

I know that I have to use the monotone convergent theorem (and I think I can use the Extraction of Subsequences), but I'm not sure that I applied them correctly, or if my proof needs to be more in debth.

So since $k≥n$, we know that$ X_n≥X_k$ or $ X_n≤X_k$, and hence $X_n$ is convergent (by the monotone convergence theorem). I think that this line $"t_n:=\inf\{X_n: k≥n\}"$ means that $t_n$ is a subsequnce of $X_n$, so by a proposition of the Extraction of Subsequences "If a subsequence converges to $l$, then every subsequence converges to $l$", if $X_n$ converges to $l$, then $t_n$ converges to $l.$

Does this make sense, and do I need to add anything?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

No, this argument has multiple logical errors.

> So since $k\geq n$,

Stop right here.  $k$ and $n$ are not fixed numbers.  For *each* $n$, we look for the infimum of $X_k$ for *all* $k$ larger than $n$.  This number is what we call $t_n$.

Aside: it's a good idea to compute $(t_n)$ for various bounded sequences $(X_n)$.  What if $X_n = 1/n$?  What if $X_n = (-1)^n$?

> we know that $X_n≥X_k$ or $X_n≤X_k$,

Well, this is true for any numbers $X_n$ and $X_k$, **but**

> and hence $(X_n)$ is convergent (by the monotone convergence theorem).

It seems you have inferred that $X_n≥X_k$ for all indices $n$ and $k$ with $n \geq k$ or that $X_n≤X_k$ for all indices $n$ and $k$ with $n \geq k$.  You inducted from a single, trivial case to the universal.

Put it another way: the only hypothesis you were given about $(X_n)$ is that it was bounded.  You seem to have shown that it is convergent.  Is it true that all bounded sequences converge?  No, so something must be wrong with this argument.

> I think that this line "$t_n:=\inf\left\{X_n: k≥n\right\}$" means that $(t_n)$ is a subsequence of $(X_n)$

It doesn't.  For instance, if $X_n = 1/n$ for each $n\geq 1$, then $t_n = 0$ for all $n$.  Not only is the constant sequence $(0)$ not a subsequence of $(1/n)$, none of the values of the sequence $(1/n)$ are zero.

---

OK, so how do we make this right?  The monotone convergence theorem is the right way to go.  You should be able to show that $(t_n)$ is bounded because $(X_n)$ is bounded, and that $(t_n)$ is monotone.  If $n' \geq n$, what can you say about the sets of indices $\left\{k : k \geq n\right\}$ and $\left\{k : k \geq n'\right\}$?  What does that imply about the infima of $X_k$ over those two sets of indices?